# Polygons area is less than polygons using terra in R

Tags: r, polygon, terra

I have a set of polygons saved as SpatVector, I'm trying to calculate the area of the polygons with the terra package. The issue is the number of areas is less than the polygons. This behaviour is unpredictable and happened randomly, however, on a remote machine!

```
#A reproducible example
 
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)
library(terra)

polygons_df<-data.frame(geom=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,
                                    5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,
                                    9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,
                                    11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,
                                    13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15),
                                    part=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                                    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                                    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                                    1,1,1),
                                    x=c(22.2,22.3,22.3,21.9,21.9,22.0,22.0,22.1,22.1,22.2,22.2,23.6,23.9,23.9,23.7,23.7,23.6,23.6,25.3,25.4,25.4,25.3,25.3,25.5,25.6,
                                            25.6,25.5,25.5,25.4,25.5,25.5,25.4,25.4,20.1,20.2,20.2,20.1,20.1,27.4,27.6,27.6,27.5,27.5,27.4,27.4,27.8,28.2,28.2,27.8,27.8,
                                            27.7,27.7,27.9,27.9,27.8,27.8,30.7,31.0,31.0,31.3,31.3,31.4,31.4,31.1,31.1,30.9,30.9,30.8,30.8,30.7,30.7,30.6,30.6,30.7,30.7,
                                            20.6,20.9,20.9,20.6,20.6,25.4,25.5,25.5,25.4,25.4,25.7,25.9,25.9,26.1,26.1,26.0,26.0,25.9,25.9,25.7,25.7,29.9,30.1,30.1,30.3,
                                            30.3,30.6,30.6,31.2,31.2,31.4,31.4,31.5,31.5,31.8,31.8,31.7,31.7,31.5,31.5,31.0,31.0,30.9,30.9,30.8,30.8,30.7,30.7,30.1,30.1,
                                            29.7,29.7,29.8,29.8,29.9,29.9,25.8,25.9,25.9,26.2,26.2,26.4,26.4,26.3,26.3,26.2,26.2,26.0,26.0,25.9,25.9,25.8,25.8,25.7,25.7,
                                            25.5,25.5,25.6,25.6,25.7,25.7,25.8,25.8,28.5,28.7,28.7,28.5,28.5,25.6,25.9,25.9,25.7,25.7,25.6,25.6,25.5,26.0,26.0,25.8,25.8,
                                            25.6,25.6,25.5,25.5,25.4,25.4,25.5,25.5),
                                    y=c(34.0,34.0,33.6,33.6,33.7,33.7,33.8,33.8,33.9,33.9,34.0,35.0,35.0,34.8,34.8,34.9,34.9,35.0,35.5,35.5,35.4,35.4,35.5,35.5,35.5,
                                            35.4,35.4,35.5,35.4,35.4,35.3,35.3,35.4,36.8,36.8,36.6,36.6,36.8,37.0,37.0,36.9,36.9,36.8,36.8,37.0,37.2,37.2,36.9,36.9,36.8,
                                            36.8,37.0,37.0,37.1,37.1,37.2,37.7,37.7,37.6,37.6,37.4,37.4,37.3,37.3,37.2,37.2,37.3,37.3,37.4,37.4,37.5,37.5,37.6,37.6,37.7,
                                            37.6,37.6,37.5,37.5,37.6,37.6,37.6,37.5,37.5,37.6,38.1,38.1,38.0,38.0,37.9,37.9,37.8,37.8,37.9,37.9,38.1,38.8,38.8,38.7,38.7,
                                            38.6,38.6,38.5,38.5,38.4,38.4,38.5,38.5,38.4,38.4,38.3,38.3,38.2,38.2,38.1,38.1,38.0,38.0,38.1,38.1,38.2,38.2,38.3,38.3,38.4,
                                            38.4,38.7,38.7,38.6,38.6,38.8,39.1,39.1,39.0,39.0,38.9,38.9,38.8,38.8,38.7,38.7,38.8,38.8,38.5,38.5,38.3,38.3,38.2,38.2,38.3,
                                            38.3,38.5,38.5,38.7,38.7,39.0,39.0,39.1,38.4,38.4,38.3,38.3,38.4,39.4,39.4,39.2,39.2,39.3,39.3,39.4,40.0,40.0,39.5,39.5,39.6,
                                            39.6,39.7,39.7,39.8,39.8,39.9,39.9,40.0))

polygons_df$hole<-rep(0,nrow(polygons_df))

polygons_cc <- sfheaders::sf_polygon(
    obj = polygons_df
    , x = "x"
    , y = "y"
    , polygon_id = "geom"
)
sf::st_crs(polygons_cc) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

polygons_cc<-vect(polygons_cc)

plot(polygons_cc)

t<- 5005000

#prepare results data frame 
result_df<-data.frame(timestep=rep(t,length(terra::values(polygons_cc))),
                                            polygon_name=paste0(sprintf("%.0f",t),"_",
                                                                                    as.vector(unlist(terra::values(polygons_cc)))),
                                            geom=unname(terra::values(polygons_cc)))
```

Where the error occurs:

```
> # calculate area of polygons / objects 
> result_df$area<-terra::project(polygons_cc,"+proj=laea +lon_0=45 +lat_0=20 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")%>%
+   expanse(unit="km")

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "area", value = c(1027.28688050304,  : 
  replacement has 15 rows, data has 18

> #another error from different shapefile: 
> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "area", value = c(123.089596546252,  : 
  replacement has 78 rows, data has 81
```

**Here is the machine information:**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/user/.conda/envs/snowflakes/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] data.table_1.14.2     reticulate_1.22       Rfast_2.0.3          
 [4] RcppZiggurat_0.1.6    Rcpp_1.0.7            REdaS_0.9.3          
 [7] MASS_7.3-54           terra_1.4-22          dplyr_1.0.7          
[10] rgeos_0.5-8           ggplot2_3.3.5         stringr_1.4.0        
[13] sf_1.0-4              raster_3.5-2          sp_1.4-6             
[16] DescTools_0.99.44     spatstat_2.2-0        spatstat.linnet_2.3-0
[19] spatstat.core_2.3-2   rpart_4.1-15          nlme_3.1-153         
[22] spatstat.geom_2.3-0   spatstat.data_2.1-0   ncdf4.helpers_0.3-6  
[25] ncdf4_1.18           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] jsonlite_1.7.2        splines_4.1.1         assertthat_0.2.1     
 [4] expm_0.999-6          gld_2.6.3             lmom_2.8             
 [7] pillar_1.6.4          lattice_0.20-45       glue_1.5.0           
[10] polyclip_1.10-0       colorspace_2.0-2      Matrix_1.3-4         
[13] spatstat.sparse_2.0-0 pkgconfig_2.0.3       s2_1.0.7             
[16] purrr_0.3.4           mvtnorm_1.1-3         scales_1.1.1         
[19] tensor_1.5            rootSolve_1.8.2.3     spatstat.utils_2.2-0 
[22] tibble_3.1.6          proxy_0.4-26          mgcv_1.8-38          
[25] generics_0.1.1        ellipsis_0.3.2        withr_2.4.2          
[28] magrittr_2.0.1        crayon_1.4.2          deldir_1.0-6         
[31] fansi_0.4.2           class_7.3-19          tools_4.1.1          
[34] lifecycle_1.0.1       Exact_3.1             munsell_0.5.0        
[37] compiler_4.1.1        e1071_1.7-9           rlang_0.4.12         
[40] classInt_0.4-3        units_0.7-2           rstudioapi_0.13      
[43] goftest_1.2-3         boot_1.3-28           wk_0.5.0             
[46] gtable_0.3.0          codetools_0.2-18      abind_1.4-5          
[49] DBI_1.1.1             R6_2.5.1              utf8_1.2.2           
[52] KernSmooth_2.23-20    stringi_1.7.5         parallel_4.1.1       
[55] vctrs_0.3.8           png_0.1-7             tidyselect_1.1.1
```

I know I can use `sf` package or loop over the polygons individually, nevertheless, I have millions of polygons and only `terra` seems to be effients in terms of resources and compuation time.
Maybe the issue comes from `terra::values()` ?
Is there a way to produce `expanse()` with the polygon ID to check where the issue is?

**EDIT:** One of the shapefile that produced the issue is [here](https://github.com/ahmathlete/Vintp_afterburner/blob/master/test.zip)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say why this happens, as I do not get that error, so perhaps it is related to using different versions of packages (and for sf, perhaps the GEOS library). Either way, I think it will work fine if you do

```
v <- vect(as.matrix(polygons_df), "polygons", crs="+proj=longlat")
p <- project(v, "+proj=laea +lon_0=45 +lat_0=20 +datum=WGS84 +units=m")
expanse(p, unit="km") |> length()
```

I believe there is an error when you first create the sf object with `sf_polygon`. The third geometry has three parts

```
polygons_df[polygons_df$geom==3, "part"] |> unique() |> length()
#[1] 3
```

But (the sf version of) `polygon_cc` is not a multipolygon

```
polygons_cc[3,]
#Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
#Geometry type: POLYGON
#Dimension:     XY
#Bounding box:  xmin: 25.3 ymin: 35.3 xmax: 25.6 ymax: 35.5
#CRS:           +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#  geom                       geometry
#3    3 POLYGON ((25.3 35.5, 25.4 3...
```

And it does not look good:

[image]

In the current workflow you simply skip that step, as I have shown above.

Another unnecessary part of your code is that you project the polygons to `lcc` (Lambert conformal conic) and then compute their area. You could, and generally should, compute in with the longitude/latitude data instead. Even though in this case the difference is very small. In fact, the default behavior of `terra` is to transform the data back to longlat to compute the area.

Comment: Hi @Robert, thanks for the answer! I will test it on the remote machine since it doesn't occur on the local machine. Also, thanks for notifying me about the error with `sf`. In the actual workflow the `polygon_cc` is produced by `terra::as.polygons()`.

Comment: Ah. In that case it may be related to using an older version of GDAL leading to invalid polygons. You can try to run makeValid()

Comment: Unfortunately, after the new installation of all packages and GDAL the error above continues to appear!

Comment: What is the version of terra and GDAL on that system? See `terra::gdal()`. And did `makeValid` help?

Comment: `terra::gdal()` is `"3.3.3"` and `library(terra)` is `terra version 1.4.22`. And `makeValid` did not change anything! I'm insisting on using terra because it reduces the workflow time from 47 sec to 14 sec and It makes a huge difference with millions of files!